# Matplotlib never shows lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

Whenever I try to visualize any data, the *plot* command doesn't work for me. *scatter*, *hist* and others work fine. For example, for this code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title("Test")
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.scatter(x=-5, y=5, color='red')
plt.scatter(x=5, y=-5, color='green')
plt.plot(x1=-10,y1=-10,x2=10,y2=10,color='blue')
plt.gcf().savefig('Test.png')
```

I would expect to get two points plus a line separating them, however all I get is the two points in the output file:

[image]

I've tried every possible backend option, various output options, different format of the plt.plot command, and I never can get any lines to show up. What could the issue be?

Thanks!

Comment: The `plt.plot` line is equivalent to `plt.plot(something=-10,whatever=-10,nothing=10,who=10,color='blue')` or more simply, `plt.plot(color='blue')`. The arguments you're giving it are meaningless to Matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = [5, -5] 
y_data = [-5, 5]

plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.show()
```

`plt.plot(x1=-10,y1=-10,x2=10,y2=10,color='blue')` well `x1` and `x2` (etc.) have no specific meaning to `matplotlib` (that I know of). You need to provide the values in separate lists.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem! I don't know why I kept using x1, y1, x2, y2 arguments and where I found them, but apparently the problem was just the wrong syntax of the command.

Comment: @May you're welcome. What confuses me is that `matplotlib` would take named arguments like that at all and not error.